# Custom Font in Windows Phone 8

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I tried to add a custom font into my application. I need it for the page title. I copied the font to a folder named "Fonts" and changed the build action to Content. In the property panel the font shows up in the font list. But when i add the font the page title doesn't change. It changes a little bit but not like the font i'm using. The odd thing is when i double click on the page title the text gets highlighted in the textblock and then the highlighted text shows in the font i want. This is confusing. What should i do to correct this?

XAML for the page title

```
<TextBlock Text="page title" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}" FontFamily="/AppName;component/Assets/Fonts/Dekers_Bold.ttf#Dekers_Bold"  />
```

Comment: Have you tried clicking rebuild? This sounds like there is overlap

Comment: No, rebuilding did not work either.

Comment: have you tried using blend to import it? It has a SUPER easy way of doing it and embeding it in the app

Comment: Yes, Tried blend too. It didn't work. There is a small change in the font weight to bold in both VS and blend. But that's about it. When i double click and highlight the text then the correct font appears

Comment: if it didn't work in blend I would suggest trying a different font from a different source and see if you can get it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add fonts as BlendEmbeddableFonts

Open your solution in blend, go to the font manager and in "Embedded Fonts", check your custom font.

Then create a resource called

```
<FontFamily           
        x:Key="CustomFont">/Wake Jake;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#FontName</FontFamily>
```

and add it as

```
FontFamily="{StaticResource CustomFont}"
```

It will work that way.
Let me know if you need further help

Answer (score 1):

If the font is located in your main WP8 project, you don't need to use the /AppName;component path. Also make sure the Dekers_Bold is actually name of the font, you should maybe try DekersBold or just Dekers:

```
FontFamily="/Assets/Fonts/Dekers_Bold.ttf#DekersBold"
```

If this is not working, try to add your font as resources first:

```
<FontFamily x:Key="Dekers">/Assets/Fonts/Dekers_Bold.ttf#DekersBold</FontFamily>
...
<TextBlock Text="page title" Margin="9,-7,0,0" FontFamily="{StaticResource Dekers}"  />
```

Comment: It did not work. Dekers_Bold is the actual name of the font. Tried installing the font to the system and it didn't work either. can this be something to do with the font itself?

Comment: When i select the font from the property panel of VS and Blend this FontFamily is set as this.

FontFamily="/QuickRecord;component/Fonts/Fonts.zip#Dekers_Bold"

what is this Fonts.zip? any way it doesn't work too :D

Comment: Have you extracted the font into single file? It must not be in a zip file.

Comment: Yes. It is extracted to a .ttf file and then added to the fonts folder in the project. Still this comes. can't understand why.

Comment: you should set the properties Build Action to Resource and Copy to Output directory to copy aways

Answer (score 1):

Any Font works in windows 8, but after you add it to your project, right click on the font, choose properties and set "Build action" to "Content". Have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not all fonts work with Windows Phone 8. It tried your font (donwloaded from dafont) in a WP 7.1 project as described [here](http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2013/06/22/TTF-Font-with-Windows-Phone-8.aspx) and it works perfectly. Doing the same in a WP 8 project... the font won't load. So, you probably have to pick another font.

Comment: With Dekers? Or did you pick another font?

Comment: Picked another one. Unfortunate :/