# Why don't certain font files work on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to use the Leitura font family in my Windows Phone 8 app with its ttf font files. Some of the fonts in the family work properly, but others don't.

I tested it with the following code:

```
<TextBlock Text="Leitura Sans Grot 3" FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/leiturasg3.ttf#Leitura Sans Grot 3" />
<TextBlock Text="Leitura Sans Italic 2" FontFamily="Assets/Fonts/leiturasg2_i.ttf#Leitura Sans Italic 2" />
```

In the above example, the **first works and the second doesn't**, it is displayed in Segoe UI. I have checked and the font files are in the correct place and their Build action is set to Content.

I tried setting the FontStyle of the second TextBlock to "Italic", but that only made it appear as italic Segoe.

If I open the ttf files in Windows, this is what I see. The first font:

[image: Information of the first font file.]

The second font:

[image: Information of the second font file.]

The font names seem to be correct, and If I install the fonts, I can see the same font names in Word for example.

What can be the reason for this? Am I specifying the FontFamily wrong?

UPDATE: I have verified that the same fonts and same XAML code works perfectly on WP7.

Comment: http://www.jayway.com/2012/10/31/using-custom-otf-fonts-in-windows-8-xaml/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Font in Windows Phone 8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074034/custom-font-in-windows-phone-8)

Comment: My question is not exactly the same because I have a font that is working perfectly and another which does not work with the same approach.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. The TTF, which worked perfectly in my Windows Phone 7 application, turns out to have licensing issue when i was using it in WP8 application. What helped me was this blog - http://nicksnettravels.builttoroam.com/post/2013/06/22/TTF-Font-with-Windows-Phone-8.aspx

Comment: This did not help, the legal rights had the value 260 for both fonts (the one which works and the one which doesn't), I tried changing it to 8 as the post suggests, but it still does not work.

Comment: I also tried exporting the font with BirdFont and FontCreator, still no luck.