# ListPicker Items not being shown in FullScreen Mode

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, toolkit, listpicker

I used a TOOLKIT ListPicker . But the items are not being shown in FullScreen Mode. Its a Blank Page on clicking ListPicker  but the items are present transparent and can even be selected. it seems blank page but items are there.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage
x:Class="Sunder_Gutka.SettingPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"

FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
mc:Ignorable="d"
shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True">

<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding BackGroundColorArray}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate" >
        <TextBlock Name="BackgroundColor" 

    Text="{Binding BackGroundColorArray}"                      
                   />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>



<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock Text="MY APPLICATION" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="page name" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

    <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="BackgroundColor"  FullModeHeader="Select Background Color:" Header="Background Color:" BorderThickness="0" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerFullModeItemTemplate}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PickerItemTemplate}" Background="#FF09043C" SelectionChanged="BackgroundColor_SelectionChanged" >

        </toolkit:ListPicker>



    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

---

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using Microsoft.Phone.Controls;
using Microsoft.Phone.Shell;

namespace Sunder_Gutka
{
    public partial class SettingPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        String[] BackGroundColorArray = { "Black", "Light Grey", "White[Default]", "Blue", "Green", "Saffron", "Yellow", "Magenta", "Dark Grey", "Red" }; //To be used in LISTPICKER

        public SettingPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BackgroundColor.ItemsSource = BackGroundColorArray; //Item Source  of listpicker

        }
        string SelectedBackgroundColor;

        private void BackgroundColor_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
             SelectedBackgroundColor = BackgroundColor.SelectedItem.ToString();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Update your DataTemplate:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate" >
        <TextBlock Name="BackgroundColor" Text="{Binding}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Its working now. I have Implemented this.

Comment: it will obviously work. But i am getting an UGLY list in full screen. I tried to style it. same lines were working fine in my another project. what could possibly be the problem here?

Comment: what do you mean by obviously ? you asked simple question and this is a answer. now you are increasing your Queries. Please be specific while asking Question. You can bind list or collection to Bindings so here its not working. try with list or observation Collection then it would work perfectly. If My answer helped you, Please mark as Answered for Future Reference for others.

Comment: What I am telling you is that I am getting the List on the page, I checked it via debugging but it is not being displayed

Comment: i have implemented in new project. The code is same as above but the Difference is only that what i have posted as answer and its working. List items are showing properly into list. for styling it you would be needed to modify its default template or modify your data template.

Answer (score 0):

By default when you display items in the FullScreen mode your items are displayed with smaller font size. So what you have to do is to change the DataTampleate of the FullScreen mode `ItemTempate` to following.. I have only increased the `FontSize` here.. You can do any styling you like.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerItemTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Name="PickerFullModeItemTemplate" >
        <TextBlock Name="BackgroundColor" Text="{Binding}" FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeLarge}" />
    </DataTemplate>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Its up to you to style the Template appropriately. Also im hoping that you are aware that `ListPicker` would only go to FullScreen mode only if you have more that 5 items in the `ListPicker`. If not you need to manually set  `ExpansionMode="FullScreenOnly"` to get it full screen.

Comment: Now it is Fine. But What about Font. I tried using :                                FontFamily="/Sunder Gutka;component/Assets/Fonts/AGENCYR.TTF#Agency FB"
But the list is not getting displayed in this font

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20074034/custom-font-in-windows-phone-8